# Toggle _ Need to click on it in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to write xpath for toggle.

Basically I want to click the following element to toggle the element:

```
Actually HTML code
```

`<label class="" for="toggleResume" data-e2e="toggleResume"><span class="flipSwitch__labelText___zr9j5">Résumés des épisodes</span><input type="checkbox" name="toggleResume" id="toggleResume" class="flipSwitch__checkbox___xwZFW" aria-label="" value="false"><span class="flipSwitch__toggle___IKEgi flipSwitch__toggle--dark___j8Khc"></span></label>`

```
After clicking toggle
```

`<label class="" for="toggleResume" data-e2e="toggleResume"><span class="flipSwitch__labelText___zr9j5">Résumés des épisodes</span><input type="checkbox" name="toggleResume" id="toggleResume" class="flipSwitch__checkbox___xwZFW" aria-label="" value="true"><span class="flipSwitch__toggle___IKEgi flipSwitch__toggle--dark___j8Khc"></span></label>`

I have tried the below xpath , but that action is not working

```
driver2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='flipSwitch__checkbox___xwZFW']").click()
        time.sleep(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated xpath:

```
//input[@id='toggleResume']//parent::label//span[2]
```

Comment: Tried 'Id', Class, Full xpath but ntg happening :(

Comment: Can you share the full html or webpage?

Comment: @Karthik the actual toggle span was on a different level than the id so you need to go back up a level and then down again. That's what the 'parent' does.

Comment: do we have any chance to write script by changed value  'True' ? sry i didnt get u that back up a level and then down again .. can u share me any example of it if possible

Comment: This site has some examples: https://www.scientecheasy.com/2019/08/xpath-axes.html/